# Demystifying Sean Parent's for_each_argument

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I saw Sean Parent's recent tweet showing the following function:

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void for_each_argument(F f, Args&&... args) {
    [](...){}((f(std::forward<Args>(args)), 0)...);
}
```

I can run it and it behaves as I would expect, but I can't understand how it works.  Is that an empty lambda?